# Date Function not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have designed a piece of code which displays an end date which is based on the select date which is selected by a user. I tried it using the new Date() function in JavaScript and it worked perfectly. However when I try to use the `var ProperDate` which is the Date the user selected (which I have converted as the same format as it would be in Javascript) the date does not display as it should.

The Code Here:

```
<script> 

$('#dSuggest').on("input", function() {
  var dInput = this.value;

  var Month = dInput.substring(5, 7); 
  var Date = dInput.substring(8, 10);
  var Year = dInput.substring(0, 4);

  var ProperDate = Month+"/"+Date+"/"+Year;

  console.log(dInput);
  $('#output').text(ProperDate);

  //var someDate = new Date(ProperDate);
  var StartDate = new Date();
  var StartDate = StartDate.toLocaleDateString();

  if(StartDate > '1/31/2016' ){
    var numberOfDaysToAdd = 365;
    ProperDate.setDate(ProperDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd); 
    //var someDate = ProperDate.toLocaleDateString();
  } else { 
    var n = someDate.getDate();
    var numberOfDaysToAdd = n;
    ProperDate.setDate(ProperDate.getDate() - numberOfDaysToAdd); 
    //var someDate = someDate.toLocaleDateString();
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = someDate; 
});

</script>
```

Comment: What are u getting in console?

Comment: @AnandG the  '$('#output').text(ProperDate);' should print out a specific date depending on today's date but that does not print out anything. document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = someDate; prints out the date the user has entered in.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're doing

```
var ProperDate = Month+"/"+Date+"/"+Year;

ProperDate.setDate(ProperDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

but `ProperDate` is not a date object, it's a string, you should be creating a date object, not a string, if you want to use date methods

```
$('#dSuggest').on("input", function() {
    var dInput = this.value;
    var Month = dInput.substring(5, 7);
    var Date = dInput.substring(8, 10);
    var Year = dInput.substring(0, 4);

    var ProperDate = new Date(Year, Month-1, Date);
    var endDate    = new Date(2016, 0, 31);

    $('#output').text(Month + "/" + Date + "/" + Year;);

    var StartDate = new Date();

    if (StartDate > endDate) {
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = 365;
    } else {
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = n;
    }
    ProperDate.setDate(ProperDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = properDate;
});
```

Comment: It's worth further noting that `toLocaleDateString` is a USER-SPECIFIC format, and doing comparisons based on it is not going to work for everyone.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - that's true, the `StartDate` shouldn't be converted to string either

Comment: Also in some years you need to add 366 days? I am not sure what the aim of the exercise is here.